# Failed to get the task for process

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode fails to get the task for process XXX. How do I solve this? (iPhone SDK 4.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523722/xcode-fails-to-get-the-task-for-process-xxx-how-do-i-solve-this-iphone-sdk-4)

I get an error message while running my app on device:

```
error: failed to launch '/Users/michalsvacha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-fvyxohsnqeujfwcjuqdnvfobusdt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.app/iSense' 
-- failed to get the task for process 46681
```

It didn't happen few days ago. The app starts and minimizes itself(no crash). This message gets logged.

Anybody ever experienced same problem? I searched here, but all the questions dealt with ad-hoc distribution, which is not my case. Other apps work smoothly.

Comment: Clean the application and reset your simulator if you are working on. Check that will help. Sometime some task get stuck with compiler and by making clean code will solve the issue.

Comment: Why should I want to reset the simulator, is there a reason if testing on device?

Comment: If you are using on device then no. But clean build the code.

Comment: You can find your answer at these posts : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488600/iphone-debugging-how-to-resolve-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process?rq=1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523722/xcode-fails-to-get-the-task-for-process-xxx-how-do-i-solve-this-iphone-sdk-4?rq=1) Hope You'll find it helpfull, if not contact me.